# I'm looking for the profgrid component for delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Goodmorning. Who can help me find the profgrid component for delphi7. I've migrated from delphi6 to 7, the profgrid component I've found on the net doesn't work. Also this company doensn't exist anymore. Maybe someone still has a good working profgrid component for me?

Comment: If the ProfGrid was a commercial product, you couldn't legally get a copy from another user even if the company no longer exists.  If you have its source code, you should be able to recompile its design-time packages without difficulty.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ProfGrid source code, locate its package (.Dpk) file(s), copy them and recompile the copied versions.  If there is more than one, usually the other package(s) will refer to it in their `Requires` clause, and you should change that to refer to the name of the copied version.  The process is straightforward, but slightly involved if you've never done it before.

I can provide more details but it's pointless if you don't have the ProfGrid source.